# How to use variables with broken_bath graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to be able to use variables as values in my graph because those values will change frequently. I am attempting to take the values from a prepared dictionary containing all the necessary data.

Here's what I was thinking, but I run into a `KeyError` every time.

```
d = {'Bob Dole': [(1100, 700), (1100, 700), (0, 0), (0, 0), (1100, 700), (1100, 700), (1100, 700)]}
name = 'Bob Dole'
tuple_range = d[name[0]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.broken_barh([tuple_range], (3, 4), facecolors='tab:blue')
ax.set_ylim(0, 30)
ax.set_xlim(800, 2100)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xlabel('Time of Day')
ax.set_yticks([3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21])
ax.set_yticklabels(names)
ax.set_title('Monday')
ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

The error:

```
{'Bob Dole': [(1100, 700), (1100, 700), (0, 0), (0, 0), (1100, 700), (1100, 700), (1100, 700)]}
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "ShiftScheduling.py", line 91, in display_selected_command
backend.display(selected_tuple[0])
  File "/user/Desktop/MachineLearning/MyPrograms/Sbackend.py", line 73, in display
sp.create_pairs(items)
  File "/user/Desktop/MachineLearning/MyPrograms/scheduleplot.py", line 140, in create_pairs
create_plot(names, times)
  File "/user/Desktop/MachineLearning/MyPrograms/scheduleplot.py", line 25, in create_plot
tuple_range = d[times[n]]
KeyError: (1100, 700)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really understand what you're trying to do but there is a problem with your dictionary and accessing the elements.

`name[0]` will return the first letter of the string, in this case `B`. If you want to use different keys (that's my understanding), iterate over them, eg.

```py
for key in d:
    print(d[key])
```

or use `keys`:

```py
for key in d.keys():
    print(d[key])
```

---

EDIT
If you're trying to access the first value of the tuple for each key, just index as:

```py
d[key][0][0]
```

If you want always the first of the tuple for all pairs per key, then:

```py
for i in d[name]:
    print(i[0])
```

Does this help?

Comment: I need to access each value for the different keys. `tuple_range` needs to be the first value for the key `Bob dole`, `(1100, 700)`. That's what I'm trying to do. Does that help?

Comment: I had forgotten some of my basic dictionary skills. After a bit of googling I realized my mistake. Thanks!